# Porting a security sandbox from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0

Tags: security, .net-4.0, appdomain

I have working .NET 2.0 addin that takes an AppDomain created by an external application and applies user-defined security policy (PolicyLevel) by using  AppDomain.SetAppDomainPolicy() method.   However, this method is obsolete in .NET 4.0 and fails at runtime. Here is a sample code:

```
AppDomain domain = ExternalApplication.GetAppDomain(); //This call is from external program which I can’t change.

PolicyLevel pl = GetUserDefinedPolicyLevel()
```

domain. SetAppDomainPolicy(pl); //This fails in .NET 4.0

I saw 4.0 example setting AppDomain security by using following call:

AppDomain.CreateDomain( string friendlyName, Evidence securityInfo, AppDomainSetup info, PermissionSet grantSet, params StrongName[] fullTrustAssemblies);

However, this API is used when an AppDomain is already created. In my situation  the addin has to use existing AppDomains.

Another solution I found was to use .config files and add `<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />` element to enforce legacy AppDomain security. This is also not an option in my case since I have an addin for applications and  I can’t add .config files.

Is there a way to change AppDomain security at runtime after it has been created in .NET 4.0?

I hope that this should be possible, since otherwise it would  look like 4.0 removed the ability to  tighten security at run-time.

Thanks